# LeetCode Python3 function annotations do not work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to copy and paste a starting function from LeetCode and have it run in Visual Studio Code.

LeetCode supports function annotation such as this:

```
class Solution:
    def printWords(self, wordList: List[str]) -> None:
        for word in wordList:
            print(word)

Solution().printWords(["cat", "dog", "cow", "bird"])
```

But if I paste that into Visual Studio Code exactly as it is I get an error. Obviously I can remove the function annotations and it'll work, which is what I normally do. However, it would be cool if I could get a solution to this.

In particular, it fails anytime I have List[int] or List[People] aka List[object].

Perhaps LeetCode is doing something non-standard?

Although I thought I was reading that this was introduced in PEP-0526 here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/ but I could be wrong.

Does anybody know how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

When running on my machine, (I'm not using Visual Studio Code, so you may have some other error), but the error I get is `NameError: name 'List' is not defined`. So I imported the List type:

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def printWords(self, wordList: List[str]) -> None:
        for word in wordList:
            print(word)

Solution().printWords(["cat", "dog", "cow", "bird"])
```

And it works as expected.

Edit: I updated my solution after reading through [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for a more accurate description of this syntax, and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html) for docs on the subject.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me as well in Visual Studio Code in my current environment. The links to the documentation are much appreciated as well.

Comment: @DavidPavel Glad to hear it. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer and/or vote it up as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)